# Counting digits in a list of list of strings and returning them as a list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

New here. Please take a look at my docstring to see what I'm trying to do:

```
def count(data):
    """ (list of list of str) -> list of int

    Return the numbers of occurrences of strings that end in digits 0, 1, or 2
    for each string.

    >>> data = [['N', 'OW1'], ['Y', 'EH1', 'S'], ['AW1', 'OW1']]
    >>> count(data)
    [1, 1, 2]
    """

    num_list = []
    num = 0

    for sublist in phonemes:
        for item in sublist:
            if item[-1].isdigit():
                num += 1
        num_list.append(num)
    return num_list
```

I don't know how to go about creating a number for each `data` `sublist`. Is that even the right approach? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right idea but you're not resetting `num` to 0 after you finish a sublist. What you're doing right now is counting a total amount of numbers 0,1,2 in all the sublists. What you want is a count for each sublist.

You also have to append `num` after you go through the whole sublist. So you need to put that out of the inner for loop body.

Revised:

```
def count(data):
    """ (list of list of str) -> list of int

    Return the numbers of occurrences of strings that end in digits 0, 1, or 2
    for each string.

    >>> data = [['N', 'OW1'], ['Y', 'EH1', 'S'], ['AW1', 'OW1']]
    >>> count(data)
    [1, 1, 2]
    """

    num_list = []
    num = 0

    for sublist in data:
        for item in sublist:
            if item[-1] in "012":
                num += 1

        # item in sublist body is over
        # num is now total occurrences of 0,1,2 in sublist
        num_list.append(num)
        num = 0
    return num_list 

print count([['N', 'OW1'], ['Y', 'EH1', 'S'], ['AW1', 'OW1']])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
def count(data):
    """ (list of list of str) -> list of int

    Return the numbers of occurrences of strings that end in digits 0, 1, or 2
    for each string.

    >>> data = [['N', 'OW1'], ['Y', 'EH1', 'S'], ['AW1', 'OW1']]
    >>> count(data)
    [1, 1, 2]
    """

    return [ len([item for item  in sublist if item[-1].isdigit()]) for sublist in data]
```

Comment: You could avoid constructing the intermediate list with `sum`: `[sum(1 for item in sublist if item[-1].isdigit()) for sublist in data]`

Answer (score 1):

Through list_comprehension.

```
>>> data = [['N', 'OW1'], ['Y', 'EH1', 'S'], ['AW1', 'OW1']]
>>> [len([j for j in i if j[-1] in "012"]) for i in data]
[1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
def count(data):
    nums = []
    for sub in data:
        occur = 0
        for i in sub:
            if i.endswith(('0', '1', '2')):
                occur += 1
        nums.append(occur)
    return nums
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = [['N', 'OW1'], ['Y', 'EH1', 'S'], ['AW1', 'OW1']]
>>> the_lengths = [i for i in map(int, [len([i for i in thelist if i[-1].isdigit()]) for thelist in data])]
>>> the_lengths
[1, 1, 2]
```